# Bash script to find specific type of files with absolute path and sort them by size

Tags: bash, find, ls

In bash, how can I search for files of a specific type (say "*.txt") in a directory and its sub-directories. Then display the files in descending order of size along with its size and full path.

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | ls -sS
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GNU find's printf option to accomplish this:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.txt' -printf "%s %h/%f\n" | sort -rg
```

To show the size in KBs instead of bytes:

```
find "$PWD" -type f -name '*.txt' -printf "%k %h/%f\n" | sort -rg
```

Comment: Nice.  Much better than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -sS
```

Should work unless there are loads and loads of matching files (man xargs(1) to see what the defaults are)

Swiss' comment below if 100% correct, `xargs -0` is the way to go since you are using `find -print0`

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs -i{} stat {} --format "%012s %n" | sort -r
```

Gives the size in bytes.

Comment: Should note that this requires GNU stat.